# Input Accessory View hides when showing alert

Tags: ios, uialertview, uialertcontroller, inputaccessoryview

I use `input accessory view` for my `viewController` to dock the view at the bottom of the screen and stick with the keyboard.

All works fine, except that when an `alert` is shown, the `input accessory view` gets hidden. It is revealed again on dismissing the `alert`.
This results in an undesirable glitch.

I tried using the `[alertView show]` API and also the new `alertController` API. Issue exists in both cases. I need support from `iOS7.0`.

Please provide your valuable comments or a solution to this problem.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Im seeing the same behaviour...

Comment: Sadly no. When I did a research, I found that input accessory views and alerts are managed by windows which are private. Modifying the same is not desirable, so I ended up using custom views docked at the bottom. I changed the bottom constraint of the same in the keyboard notification methods by using the same animation duration and animation available through the notification.